# Application to create videos

Tags: video, appmenu

I'm a new user of Ubuntu gnome, and I'm looking for a specific application. In different videos from youtube.com, I would like to select samples from several videos to create one. For example, amongst video_1, video_2, video_3, ...., video_n, I would like to be able to take the time interval 1 from the video_1, plus the time interval 2 from the video_2, plus ....,Plus the time interval n of the video_n for a single video. Could anyone be able to suggest me such application from Ubuntu I could use to do that (and how to do that, if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cinelerra is a video editing and compositing software package. It is designed for the Linux operating system, also includes a video compositing engine, allowing the user to perform advanced compositing operations such as keying and mattes.

http://cinelerra.org/2015/index.php/2013-11-18-20-52-06/manuals
http://cinelerra.org/2015/index.php/2013-11-18-20-52-06/tutorial-videos